# Swift adding Launch Screen cause main app screen to preform odd

Tags: xcode, swift

This is with out launch screen.
[image]

This is with launch screen.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I might have done wrong? 
Ok I had paste in sections because it would complain about the format other wise.

```
import SpriteKit
```

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate

```
var bird: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var overlay: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "System-Bold")

var ground1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var ground2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

var background1: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var background2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

var mainPipe: Pipe = Pipe()
var pipes: [Pipe] = []

var space: Float = 90
var prevNum: Float = 0

var maxRange: Float = 175
var minRange: Float = -100

var birdCategory: UInt32 = 1
var pipeCategory: UInt32 = 2

var score: Int = 0

var movingSpeed: CGFloat = 3.3

var isMoving: Bool       = false
var isGroundMoving: Bool = true

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
mainPipe = Pipe(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width / 6, height: view.bounds.size.height))

    overlay = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: self.view!.bounds.size)

    overlay.alpha = 0.7
    overlay.zPosition = 11

    overlay.position.x += overlay.size.width / 2
    overlay.position.y += overlay.size.height / 2

    background1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")

    background1.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 0.5
    background2.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 1.5

    background1.position.y = view.bounds.size.height * 0.5
    background2.position.y = view.bounds.size.height * 0.5

    background1.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    background2.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    ground1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")
    ground2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")

    ground1.size.width = view.bounds.size.width + 2
    ground2.size.width = view.bounds.size.width + 2

    ground1.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 0.5
    ground2.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 1.5

    ground1.position.y = ground1.size.height * 0.4
    ground2.position.y = ground2.size.height * 0.4

    ground1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground1.size)
    ground2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground2.size)

    ground1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    ground1.zPosition = 10
    ground2.zPosition = 10

    ground1.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    ground2.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 8)
    bird.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    bird.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = pipeCategory
    bird.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask   = pipeCategory

    bird.zPosition = 9
    //bird.lineWidth = 0

    bird = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jennaface")
    //bird.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.width / 2.5)
    bird.position  = CGPoint(x: 150, y: view.bounds.height / 2 - 10)

    scoreLabel.position.x = 13
    scoreLabel.position.y = view.bounds.height - 50

    scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
    scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left

    scoreLabel.hidden = true

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -3.5)

    self.addChild(background1)
    self.addChild(background2)

    self.addChild(ground1)
    self.addChild(ground2)

    self.addChild(bird)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)

func spawnPipeRow(offs: Float)
{
    let offset = offs - space / 2

    let pipeBot = mainPipe.copy() as Pipe
    let pipeTop = mainPipe.copy() as Pipe

    pipeBot.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BotPipe")
    pipeTop.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "TopPipe")

    pipeBot.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    pipeTop.texture!.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    pipeBot.isBottom = true

    let xx = Float(self.view!.bounds.size.width)

    self.setPositionRelativeBot(pipeBot, x: xx, y: offset)
    self.setPositionRelativeTop(pipeTop, x: xx, y: offset + space)

    pipeBot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeBot.size)
    pipeTop.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeTop.size)

    pipeBot.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    pipeTop.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

    pipeBot.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory
    pipeTop.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = birdCategory

    pipeBot.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = birdCategory
    pipeTop.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = birdCategory

    pipes.append(pipeBot)
    pipes.append(pipeTop)

    self.addChild(pipeBot)
    self.addChild(pipeTop)
}

func setPositionRelativeBot(node: SKSpriteNode, x: Float, y: Float)
{
    let xx = (Float(node.size.width) / 2) + x
    let yy = Float(self.view!.bounds.size.height) / 2 - (Float(node.size.height) / 2) + y

    node.position.x = CGFloat(xx)
    node.position.y = CGFloat(yy)
}

func setPositionRelativeTop(node: SKSpriteNode, x: Float, y: Float)
{
    let xx = (Float(node.size.width) / 2) + x
    let yy = Float(self.view!.bounds.size.height) / 2 + (Float(node.size.height) / 2) + y

    node.position.x = CGFloat(xx)
    node.position.y = CGFloat(yy)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    if (!bird.physicsBody!.dynamic)
    {
        //First touch

        self.spawnPipeRow(0)

        bird.physicsBody!.dynamic = true

        bird.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 175)

        scoreLabel.hidden = false

        isMoving = true
    } else if (isMoving)
    {
        var vel: CGFloat = 200

        if (self.view!.bounds.size.height - bird.position.y < 85)
        {
            vel -= 85 - (self.view!.bounds.size.height - bird.position.y)
        }

        bird.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, vel)
    } else
    {
        overlay.removeFromParent()

        for pi in pipes
        {
            pi.removeFromParent()
        }

        pipes.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        score = 0

        bird.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        bird.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: view!.bounds.size.height / 2 - 10)

        scoreLabel.hidden = true

        isGroundMoving = true
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
{
    if (isGroundMoving)
    {
        ground1.position.x -= movingSpeed
        ground2.position.x -= movingSpeed

        if (ground1.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
        {
            ground1.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 - 2
        }

        if (ground2.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
        {
            ground2.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 - 2
        }

        background1.position.x -= movingSpeed / 3
        background2.position.x -= movingSpeed / 3

        if (background1.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
        {
            background1.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 - 2
        }

        if (background2.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
        {
            background2.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 - 2
        }

        if (isMoving)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < pipes.count; i++)
            {
                let pipe = pipes[i]

                if (pipe.position.x + (pipe.size.width / 2) < 0)
                {
                    pipe.removeFromParent()

                    continue
                }

                if (pipe.position.x + (pipe.size.width / 2) < self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2 && pipe.isBottom && !pipe.pointAdded)
                {
                    score++

                    pipe.pointAdded = true
                }

                pipe.position.x -= movingSpeed

                if (i == pipes.count - 1)
                {
                    if (pipe.position.x < self.view!.bounds.width - pipe.size.width * 2.0)
                    {
                        self.spawnPipeRow(self.randomOffset())
                    }
                }
            }

            scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!)
{
    if (isMoving)
    {
        isMoving = false
        isGroundMoving = false

        bird.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

        for pi in pipes
        {
            pi.physicsBody = nil
        }

        self.addChild(overlay)
    } else
    {
        bird.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    }
}

func randomOffset() -> Float
{
    let max = maxRange - prevNum
    let min = minRange - prevNum

    var rNum:  Float = Float(arc4random() % 61) + 40 //40 - 100
    var rNum1: Float = Float(arc4random() % 31) + 1

    if (rNum1 % 2 == 0)
    {
        var tempNum = prevNum + rNum

        if (tempNum > maxRange)
        {
            tempNum = maxRange - rNum
        }

        rNum = tempNum
    } else
    {
        var tempNum = prevNum - rNum

        if (tempNum < minRange)
        {
            tempNum = minRange + rNum
        }

        rNum = tempNum
    }

    prevNum = rNum

    return rNum
}

class Pipe: SKSpriteNode
{
    var isBottom: Bool = false

    var pointAdded: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: i think you are using Sprite kit.Just create two GameScenes one for splash screen and other your game play screen

Comment: How do I link the scene to the launch screen? I am using a launch screen.xib file for my launch.

Comment: Also what code do I need to show to help find the answer?

Comment: Post your gamescene code which represents above output

Comment: i was having problems using a launch screen xib too.  i went the old school way and just added a launch image in my Images.xcassets